# How to perform a check on vowels?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function `score :: Char -> Int` that converts a character to its score. Each
letter starts with a score of *1*; *1* is added to the score of a character if it is a vowel
*(a, e, i, o, u)* and *1* is added to the score of a character if it is upper case; a character
that is not a letter scores *0*. For example,

```
score 'A' == 3
score 'a' == 2
score 'B' == 2
score 'b' == 1
score '.' == 0
```

This is my code so far:

```
n :: Int -> Int
n = 0

isVowel :: Char -> Char
isVowel x = [if x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' ||
                x == 'o' || x == 'u' then x else x]

score :: Char -> Int
score x  =
    [if isAlpha x then n+1 else n ]
    [if isUpper x then n+1 else n ]
    [if isVowel x then n+1 else n ]
```

something is definitely wrong with this code, but I cannot find what. Specifically, is there any way to write a function for detecting vowels? I'm not even sure that the one I wrote is correct. Or do I change the type of `isVowel` to `Char -> Bool` then if `isVowel = True` will that work? I will be thankful for any help provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing expression in a (singleton) list. Furthermore your `isVowel` should return a `Bool`. We thus can implement this as:

```
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel x = x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u'
```

You however forgot the uppercase vowels (AEIOU) We can write this more compact with an `elem` check:

```
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel x = x `elem` "aeiouAEIOU"
```

or even with a section of an infix operator:

```
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel = (`elem` "aeiouAEIOU")
```

In your `score` function you seem to use a variable `n` but that variable is not defined somewhere, and furthermore in Haskell all variables are immutable: once assigned a value, you can no longer change its value.

We can calculate the score by adding three items together:

```
score :: Char -> Int
score x  = (if isAlpha x then 1 else 0) + (if isUpper x then 1 else 0) + (if isVowel x then 1 else 0)
```

Since `Bool` is a member of the [**`Enum`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) where `False` maps to `0` and `True` maps to `1`, we can make use of [**`fromEnum :: Enum a => a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromEnum) to automatically do the conversion:

```
score :: Char -> Int
score x  = fromEnum (isAlpha x) + fromEnum (isUpper x) + fromEnum (isVowel x)
```

or, as [@leftroundabout says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434812/how-to-perform-a-check-on-vowels/69434877?noredirect=1#comment122726591_69434877): we can also make use of list comprehension and work with a list of checks, so:

```
score :: Char -> Int
score x  = length [ 1 | p <- [isAlpha, isUpper, isVowel], p x ]
```

Comment: I'm not really a fan of the `fromEnum` idea. Better something like `length [() | p<-[isAlpha, isUpper, isVowel], p x]`

Comment: Thank you! I understand what the code means now. I have ran the code, but the output for score 'A' == 2. The code is completely correct and should output a 3, so what could be the error? (I used the elem check option for the isVowel checking if that helps)

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode: you forgot to add `AEIOU` to the characters for the `isVowel` test.

Answer (score 3):

You write:

```
n :: Int -> Int
n = 0
```

`n` is defined to be `0`. It will always be `0`. We can't change that, we've defined it that way.

It's also not a function, it's just `Int`.

```
n :: Int
n = 0

isVowel :: Char -> Char
isVowel x = [if x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' ||
                x == 'o' || x == 'u' then x else x]
```

Some parts are good here obviously,  but first, why the brackets? We don't need them here at all. Second, the return type should be `Bool`:

```
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel x =  if x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' ||
                x == 'o' || x == 'u' then True else False
```

but then the `if` just returns its test as is, so there's no need for it either:

```
isVowel :: Char -> Bool
isVowel x =     x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' ||
                x == 'o' || x == 'u'
```

Now, finally, the `score`:

```
score :: Char -> Int
score x  =
    [if isAlpha x then n+1 else n ]
    [if isUpper x then n+1 else n ]
    [if isVowel x then n+1 else n ]
```

Here `n+1 == 0+1 == 1`, so no need for that `n`. And in fact,

```
score :: Char -> Int
score x  =  sum (
    [1 | isAlpha x ]  ++
    [1 | isUpper x ]  ++
    [1 | isVowel x ]  )
```

is all we need.

Comment: Thank you! For the final product, if I'm not mistaken, is it a list comprehension? And I've never seen a ++ operator before. Does it denote something or is it simply an addition operator for integers?

Comment: `++` concatenates lists: `[a,b,c] ++ [d,e] = [a,b,c , d,e]`. yes, each of the three components is a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

When you wrote

```
score x  =
    [if isAlpha x then n+1 else n]
    [if isUpper x then n+1 else n]
    [if isVowel x then n+1 else n]
```

you probably had something in mind like in Python

```py
def score(x):
    n = 0
    if isAlpha(x): n+=1
    if isUpper(x): n+=1
    if isVowel(x): n+=1
    return n
```

As the other answers noted, this can – and should – just be expressed with `sum` or `length`, but in more general case of something similar (sequential similar updates to a variable) you would use a *fold*:

```
import Data.List

score x = foldl' (\n p -> if p x then n+1 else n) 0
           [isAlpha, isUpper, isVowel]
```

or even

```
score x = foldl' (flip id) 0
   [ \n -> if isAlpha x then n+1 else n
   , \n -> if isUpper x then n+1 else n
   , \n -> if isVowel x then n+1 else n
   ]
```

It is even possible (though not recommended in this case) to make it look completely imperative, by working in the [state monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html):

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

score = (`execState`0) $ do
   when (isAlpha x) $ modify (+1)
   when (isUpper x) $ modify (+1)
   when (isVowel x) $ modify (+1)
```

Comment: folding over the list of predicates, nice. there's also `score = sum . sequence preds`. well, not quite, but can be made to work somehow, probably.

Comment: Yeah, old habits I guess. Thanks for the answer! By the way, what does the  " fold1' (\n  " part mean, in terms of code?

Comment: @idontknowhowtocode `\n p -> ...` is a _lambda expression_. That's too much of a broad and all-important concept in Haskell to explain it here.